# How to convert a data.frame table to an xts object

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

i downloaded price data from Thomson Reuters Datastream into excel and created a csv file. The resulting csv file is a data.frame object. I have already set the date column as a `date` using the `as.date` function. The resulting table is a `data.frame` with 42 columns, the first column being the `date` column and the other 41 being price data for different companies. The class of the price data is `'numeric'`.
The table looks something like this:

```
       date           TickerA      TickerB      TickerC
    1  2000-01-03       20           NA            40
    2  2000-01-04       21           33            42
    3  2000-01-05       22           32            NA
    4  .
    5  .
    6  .
```

Note that some prices are missing since some companies have gone bankrupt or were founded later in the observation period. Now, i would like to use the Return.calculate function from the PerformanceAnalytics package, which converts a table of prices to a table of returns, something like this:

```
      date           TickerA     TickerB     TickerC
   1  2000-01-03       NA          NA          NA
   2  2000-01-04      0.049        NA         0.049
   3  2000-01-05      0.047      -0.031        NA
   4   .
   5   .
   6   .
```

The code until now looks like this:

```
test <- read.csv("data.csv")
date <- as.Date(test$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
data <- cbind(date, test[,-1])
```

When i try to apply the Return.calculate function this happens:

```
returns <- Return.calculate(data, method = 'log')
'Error in checkData(prices, method = 'xts'): the data cannot be converted into a time series. If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'. Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.'
```

And when i try to convert `data` into an xts object this shows up:

```
xtsdata <- xts(data, order.by = data$date)
'Error in xts(data, order.by = data$date): 'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'.'
```

I don't understand this, since my date column is type `date` and my price columns are type `numeric`. In short, i think my problems could be solved if i could just convert the table to an xts object. Does anybody have an idea what the issue with the table could be? I am grateful for every tip, have a good one :)

Comment: Did you check that the date conversion in `date <- as.Date(test$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` actually give you non-NA dates? just do a `summary(date)` to see if there are any NAs. Perhaps your format string is incorrect? Could it be %Y-%m-%d, for example?

Comment: Thank you, according to R there are 134 NA's in there. When i go through the table however, i can't find any. The format string for date seems to be correct, in excel and the original csv file, the date looks like this 1/3/2000. And after applying the as.Date function, it is 2000-01-03.

Comment: Check `test$date`. 1/3/2000 is ambiguous - it could also be 1 March 2000, so maybe your format string should be `%d/%m/%Y`? It's probably worth comparing the string values in `test$date` against your csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you have is as in the Note at the end either of these work:

```
library(xts)

# 1
z <- read.csv.zoo("data.csv", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
x <- as.xts(z)

# 2    
DF <- read.csv("data.csv")
z <- read.zoo(DF, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
x <- as.xts(z)

# Calculate returns

library(PerformanceAnalytics)

Return.calculate(x, method = 'log')
##               TickerA     TickerB    TickerC
## 2000-01-03         NA          NA         NA
## 2000-01-04 0.04879016          NA 0.04879016
## 2000-01-05 0.04652002 -0.03077166         NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "date,TickerA,TickerB,TickerC
01/03/2000,20,,40
01/04/2000,21,33,42
01/05/2000,22,32,
"
cat(Lines, file = "data.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, #2 worked for me. The data is now in "xts" "zoo" format. Unfortunately however the prices are now also "xts" "zoo" and Return.calculate can't compute anything.

Comment: Both should work if the data is in the format assumed in the Note.  I have revised the assumed format.  The first one is clearly more compact.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for helping, i greatly appreciate your time :). I have figured out that in the excel file there were some prices in the observation greater than $1000. Accidentaly the format was like this: $1,145.32, which prompted R to use factors in this column. After i changed the format to $1145.32, it worked perfectly fine with #1 and #2. Have a good one ;)